# ios Set UIScrollView's origin position

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

By default as we all know, a view's origin is at the top-left corner of the iPhone screen.
I'm trying to do something very simple with no luck, to change it!
I would like to set my UIScrollView's origin to the bottom-left corner (programmatically ofc).
I was hoping to avoid transformations (if needed)...is there a simple way to do so?

Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width, -self.view.frame.size.height];
```

i am not sure what your looking for but the above line will set the origin of scrollview at bottom left, but scrollview will still be visible on the whole view if thats what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This category will give you a convenience property that can be used to manipulate a UIView by its lower left origin:

```
@interface UIView (LowerLeftOrigin)

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint lowerLeftOrigin;

@end


@implementation UIView (LowerLeftOrigin)

- (void) setLowerLeftOrigin:(CGPoint)lowerLeftOrigin
{
    self.frame = CGRectMake(lowerLeftOrigin.x, 
                            lowerLeftOrigin.y - self.bounds.size.height, 
                            self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
}

- (CGPoint) lowerLeftOrigin
{
    return CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                       self.frame.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to make a Scroll View that fits to the left bottom corner of your view.

You can do that. Let's say your scroll view's size is 100x100.

```
UIScrollView* sc = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 360, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:sc];
```

That Scroll View's left bottom corner has the same point with your View.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can change one any one position by leaving others as default

1.Before modified

```
UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,500)];
```

2.If need to modify any one

```
UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

// or

UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,10,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

//or

UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,320,self.view.frame.size.height)];

//or

UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,500)];
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.scrollView` property `contentOffset`